# Examine assembly program using GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm very new to assembly - we learned how to read it just last week in class. I'm working on a pset and got stuck. The purpose of the pset is to be able to figure out what the assembly code for each phase is doing and give the program the correct input so it doesn't fail. I figured out the first phase, but I'm just not sure how to approach the second phase. The following is only part of the code, but gives an idea of what I'm looking at.

```
<redacted>
```

"explode bomb" causes the program to fail. Right now I'm setting a breakpoint before "explode bomb" is called, before "read_six_numbers" is called, and using info register & stepi as well as print statements to try to see what the correct input for this part of the program is. However, I'm just really unsure as to how to approach this. Using info register doesn't give any sequences of 6 numbers, and I'm really not sure if that's what I should even be looking for.

Since this is a pset I'll be adding this link to my pset README when committing it, and I'd really appreciate explanations over straight solutions, since there are more phases after this part I have to solve and being introduced to techniques with gdb to solve things like this would be really, really helpful.

Comment: Look at the gdb `x` (examine) command. That will allow you to look ahead a given number of values.  For example `x/8x 0x400500` will allow you to look at the next 8 hex values beginning at memory address `0x400500`. Other than that it looks like you are using the correct tools.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!! I'll definitely look more into it. I've looked at the code for a bit and thought about different places I would want GDB to stop to look at the values, especially at compare points, since I could possibly expose the values the program expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out - the key to this part was setting multiple breakpoints or using si to figure out how the program was functioning. I won't post a direct answer because that's probably against school rules, but stepping through the program was crucial to figuring out the correct input.

Shoutout to David for teaching me about x GDB commands - they're really, really helpful for this.